# Facebook Authentication for Mobile app accessing Django backend via REST

Tags: facebook, titanium-mobile, django-rest-framework

I am developing a mobile app based on Titanium Mobile and using its [FB Module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Facebook) that authenticates the user via FaceBook. Now, we will also be implementing a web service for this mobile application implemented with the [Django Rest Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/).

I'm wondering how best to implement this securely so that once the user is authenticated with FaceBook the mobile app can also be authenticated to the Django backend.

Comment: Were you able to get some info in it? If yes, can you share?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We decided to scrap the idea and go another route entirely.